# Retry for specific number of times on firebase transaction abort

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using firebase in appengine:

```
DatabaseReference upvotesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "TEST" );

    upvotesRef.runTransaction( new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction( MutableData mutableData ) {
            // null cases handled
            mutableData.setValue( object );
            return Transaction.success( mutableData );
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete( DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {
            if( ! committed ) {
                // Retry for x times
                // Throw error on the (x+1)th time
            }
        }
    }, false );
```

For a particular node :
1. The transaction is failing on the first time and not retrying. 
2. Works fine from the second time.

So, I want to retry the transaction for x times in case of any error, and throw an exception on the (x+1)th time of execution. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the transaction failing on the first attempt?

Comment: Firebase transactions auto-retry already. What error are you getting?

Comment: DatabaseError: The operation had to be aborted due to a network disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
 @Override
 public Transaction.Result doTransaction( MutableData mutableData ) {

     // null cases handled
     if(mutableData.getValue() == null){
        return Transaction.success( mutableData );
     }

     mutableData.setValue( object );
     return Transaction.success( mutableData );
 }
```

The added code solved my problem